# C# select elements from IList

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of objects, `IList<O>`.
`O` has several properties but only two of them are relevant: `Date` and `Duration`.

I want to "split" the list into several lists that contain only the objects that have matching Date and Duration Properties.

Example:

```
0- Date==1, Duration==7  
1- Date==1, Duration==7  
2- Date==2, Duration==7  
3- Date==2, Duration==7  
4- Date==2, Duration==14  
5- Date==2, Duration==14
```

Desired result (IList<IList<O>>):

```
0-  
 0- Date==1, Duration==7  
 1- Date==1, Duration==7  
1-  
 0- Date==2, Duration==7  
 1- Date==2, Duration==7  
2-  
 0- Date==2, Duration==14  
 1- Date==2, Duration==14
```

I know this can be done with some LINQ selects but am not sure how.

Comment: I've followed up on that link Brian R. Bondy provided, i`m sure with more reading i would have found the solution there but then Ben Lings provided the solution. The other two answers from call me Steve and Mark Brackett were close but they only grouped by date.

The chosen answer works great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
var query = 
    from item in list
    group item by new { item.Date, item.Duration } into g
    select g.toList();
var result = query.toList();
```

This creates an anonymous class with the properties that you want to group by. It then expands the `IGrouping` to a `List` of the original type. The query is then run to produce the outer `List`.

Comment: all though i appreciate all the answers this is the one that does exactly what i need. thanks to everybody for taking the time.

Answer (score 2):

See the [grouping operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336754.aspx#simple1) for nested LINQ results.

Here is an example from the site I linked to:

```
public void Linq40()
{
    int[] numbers = { 5, 4, 1, 3, 9, 8, 6, 7, 2, 0 };

    var numberGroups =
        from n in numbers
        group n by n % 5 into g
        select new { Remainder = g.Key, Numbers = g };

    foreach (var g in numberGroups)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Numbers with a remainder of {0} when divided by 5:", g.Remainder);
        foreach (var n in g.Numbers)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(n);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This will give you an `IEnumerable<IGrouping<Date, O>>`, which is close to what you want.

```
list.GroupBy(i => new { Date = i.Date, Duration = i.Duration });
```

To get an actual `IList<IList<O>>`, you'll have to further refine by getting the `IEnumerable<O>` out of the `IGrouping`:

```
list.GroupBy(i => new { Date = i.Date, Duration = i.Duration })
    .Select(g => g.ToList()).ToList();
```

Comment: @drupop - Guess I should work on my reading comprehension. ;) Fixed.

Answer (score 2):

I am learning Linq, so I tried to find out a solution:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace so_listobj
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<O> anOList = new List<O>();
            List<List<O>> aGroupOList = new List<List<O>>();

            anOList.Add(new O(1, 7));
            anOList.Add(new O(1, 7));
            anOList.Add(new O(2, 2));
            anOList.Add(new O(2, 2));
            anOList.Add(new O(2, 14));
            anOList.Add(new O(2, 14));

            Console.Out.WriteLine("Initial state");

            foreach (O o in anOList)
            {
                Console.Out.WriteLine(o);
            }

            var grp =
                from o in anOList
                group o by o.Date into a
                select new {Date = a.Key, aGroupOList = a  };

            Console.Out.WriteLine("after grouping");

            foreach (var _ob in grp)
            {
                foreach (var _anotherOList in _ob.aGroupOList)
                {
                    Console.Out.WriteLine("{0} {1}", _ob.Date, _anotherOList.ToString());
                }
            }
        }
    }


    class O
    {
        private int  _Odate;
        private int _Oduration;

        public O(int date, int duration)
        {
            _Odate = date;
            _Oduration = duration;
        }

        public int Date
        {
            get { return _Odate; }
            set { _Odate = value; }
        }
        public int Duration
        {
            get { return _Oduration; }
            set { _Oduration = value; }
        }


        public override String ToString()
        {
            return String.Format("- Date :{0}\t Duration:{1}", _Odate, _Oduration);
        }
    }
}
```