# C# Select elements in list as List of string

Tags: c#, linq

In C# i need to get all values of a particular property from an object list into list of string

```
List<Employee> emplist = new List<Employee>()
                                {
                                 new Employee{ EID=10, Ename="John"},
                                 new Employee{ EID=11, Ename="Adam"},
                                 new Employee{ EID=12, Ename="Ram"}
                                };
List<string> empnames = emplist.//get all Enames in 'emplist' object into list
                         //using linq or list functions or IENumerable  functions
```

I am familiar with the foreach method to extract the value but I want to know **if \ how its possible use linq or IENumerable functions** or some shorter code to extract values from the list object property values into a string object.

My query is Similar to [C# select elements from IList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2616891/c-sharp-select-elements-from-ilist)  but i want the the result as list of string

Answer (score 101, accepted):

```
List<string> empnames = emplist.Select(e => e.Ename).ToList();
```

This is an example of [Projection in Linq](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738447.aspx). Followed by a `ToList` to resolve the `IEnumerable<string>` into a `List<string>`.

Alternatively in Linq syntax (head compiled):

```
var empnamesEnum = from emp in emplist 
                   select emp.Ename;
List<string> empnames = empnamesEnum.ToList();
```

Projection is basically representing the current type of the enumerable as a new type. You can project to anonymous types, another known type by calling constructors etc, or an enumerable of one of the properties (as in your case).

For example, you can project an enumerable of `Employee` to an enumerable of `Tuple<int, string>` like so:

```
var tuples = emplist.Select(e => new Tuple<int, string>(e.EID, e.Ename));
```

Comment: The power of LINQ.. <Victory!> (Johnny Drama's Voice)

Answer (score 10):

```
List<string> empnames = (from e in emplist select e.Enaame).ToList();
```

Or

```
string[] empnames = (from e in emplist select e.Enaame).ToArray();
```

Etc...