# List out of List C#

Tags: c#

what if i have one this and want another out of it for example, I have this,

```
List<User> users = GetAllUsers();
```

but what I want is Listof firstname,

```
List<string> firstNames = GetAllUsers();
```

Is it possible to convert `List<Users>` into `List<string>` of `FirstName`s  out of box ?

Edit

FirstName is property of User object, and it's string.

```
public class User
{
   public string FirstName{get; set;}
   public string LastName{get; set;}
   public string CustomProperty{get; set;}
}
```

Comment: because it is impossible to answer without more information. What does 'out of box' mean?

Comment: Can you convert a car to a wheel? What type is FirstName and how do you extract it from a Users instance?

Comment: Can you show the class `User` and the class `FirstName`?

Comment: Ok I updated it @thumbmunkeys

Comment: @CustomizedName List<FirstName> doesnt make sense then

Comment: Here is one of the duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9885748/c-sharp-select-elements-in-list-as-list-of-string So if someone  wants to reopen this question then just to close it as duplicate.

Comment: I am very sorry to interrupt this bullying, but it is completely clear, what op asked for. And there is a perfect answer right down below

Comment: @Michał it wasn't at all clear when the question was asked. Furthermore the question is duplicate

Comment: @Michał: OP has clarified the question only few minutes ago. Before the `List<string>` was a `List<FirstName>`. Now it's just a duplicate.

Comment: @TimSchmelter not few minutes ago, and it was duplicate by chance, look at the keywords in other question

Comment: @CustomizedName: don't get me wrong, but i have found the duplicate in few seconds. "List out of List" is pretty vague and the `List<UserName>` was just misleading. Now since it's clear that you want a `List<string>` it was easy to found ["C# Select elements in list as List of string"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9885748/c-sharp-select-elements-in-list-as-list-of-string).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If `FirstName` is a string property of the `User` class, try

```
List<string> firstNames = GetAllUsers().Select(x => x.FirstName).ToList();
```

Comment: how List<FirstName> is a list of string?

Comment: @Infer-On I'm not 100% sure, but guess PO might have a property named `FirstName` of type `string`.

Comment: @Inter-On PS. `FirstName` is indeed a property of type `string`, see the updated question.

Answer (score 1):

Use LINQ:

```
List<FirstName> firstNames = GetAllUsers().Select(x => x.FirstName).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

As you edited your post and your property is string:

```
   List<string> firstNames = GetAllUsers().Select(x => x.FirstName).ToList();
```